React Native crashing with SoLoader after upgrading to SDK 34
I upgraded the Android SDK to 34 on my React Native app. It worked fine for debug mode but I later found out that every Android client was crashing in production. I've spent a few hours with debugging this and googling but nothing is working. I'm suspecting it's because I upgraded Gradle and thus it doens't know how to package the app anymore. Here are some relevant changes when I upgraded:

Switched hermes to true, it was false before.
Added this to app/build.gradle: implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'
Patched receivers on MainApplication.java:

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
import com.reactnativecommunity.cameraroll.CameraRollPackage;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  @Override
  public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
          return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
      } else {
          return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
      }
  }



Changed compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 34
Upgraded com.android.tools.build:gradle from 7.0.4 to 7.1.2
Added this to android/build.gradle:

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs += ["-Xlint:deprecation", "-Xlint:unchecked"]
    }


When I have been testing the various solutions I have git stashed and ran gradlew clean and gradlew assembleRelease, then I used adb install to move the app there.
Error log:
07-31 13:49:04.775  5030  5079 D Launcher.Model: Loader.updatePackage com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:04.778  5030  5079 V LauncherApps: Returning activity for profile UserHandle{0} : ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity}
07-31 13:49:04.790  3631  4052 D PackageManager: getComponentMetadataForIconTray : com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity does not exist in mServices
07-31 13:49:04.790  3631  4052 D PackageManager: getComponentMetadataForIconTray : com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity does not exist in mProviders
07-31 13:49:04.790  3631  4052 D PackageManager: getComponentMetadataForIconTray : com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity does not exist in mReceivers
07-31 13:49:04.792  3631  4052 D PackageManager: getSelectedMetaData : packageName(com.mycompany.myapp) or Metadata strings {[Ljava.lang.String;@7128e06}
07-31 13:49:04.800  5030  5079 D LauncherActivityInfo: packageName: com.mycompany.myapp, supportTheme: false, height: 192, width: 192, density: 640
07-31 13:49:04.824  5030  5079 V LauncherApps: Returning activity for profile UserHandle{0} : ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity}
07-31 13:49:04.824  5030  5079 D DataLoader: updatePackage:com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:04.826  5030  5079 I AppsModel: addOrUpdater cn = ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity} , UserHandle{0}
07-31 13:49:04.827  5030  5079 I AppsModel: addOrUpdater update item = IconInfo(title=myapp intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.mycompany.myapp/.MainActivity (has extras) } id=129 type=0 container=-102 screen=1 cellX=3 cellY=2 spanX=1 spanY=1 rank=11 hidden=0 dropPos=null user=UserHandle{0})
07-31 13:49:04.828  5030  5030 D AppsAdapter: updateItem : (id=129, container=-102, screen=1, rank=11, myapp, false)
07-31 13:49:04.830  5030  5079 I PostPositionController: addItem() - com.mycompany.myapp, isWidgetOnly : true
07-31 13:49:08.601  3631  7968 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN typ=null flg=0x10200000 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity}} from uid 10008
07-31 13:49:08.602  3631  4729 D ActivityManagerPerformance: Received MSG_CFMS_HINT_AMS_SWITCH pkgName: com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.615  3631  3722 D ViewRootImpl@bd5a48d[myapp]: setView = DecorView@eb36653[myapp] TM=true MM=false
07-31 13:49:08.621  3631  4052 D ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked, ANIM_CUSTOM_SCALE_UP, task.getRootActivity() : ActivityRecord{c96ac8c u0 com.mycompany.myapp/.MainActivity t871}, task.getTaskToReturnTo() : 1
07-31 13:49:08.622  3631  4052 D StorageManagerService: getExternalStorageMountMode : final mountMode=1, uid : 10212, packageName : com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.622  3631  4052 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted:com.mycompany.myapp user:0
07-31 13:49:08.622  3631  4052 D ActivityManager: package  com.mycompany.myapp, user - 0 is SDcard whitelisted
07-31 13:49:08.622  3631  4052 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:com.mycompany.myapp user:0
07-31 13:49:08.626  3631  3722 D ViewRootImpl@bd5a48d[myapp]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
07-31 13:49:08.626  3631  3722 V WindowManager: Relayout Window{4283642 u0 Splash Screen com.mycompany.myapp}: viewVisibility=0 req=1080x1848 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#20 ty=3 fl=#81830118 pfl=0x20011 wanim=0x10302fd vsysui=0x600 needsMenuKey=2 colorMode=0 naviIconColor=0}
07-31 13:49:08.628  3194  3194 I SurfaceFlinger: id=188 createSurf (1080x1920),1 flag=404, Splash Screen com.mycompany.myapp#0
07-31 13:49:08.631  3631  3722 D ViewRootImpl@bd5a48d[myapp]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 515257561088} changed=true
07-31 13:49:08.633  3631  4052 I ActivityManager: Start proc 17500:com.mycompany.myapp/u0a212 for activity com.mycompany.myapp/.MainActivity
07-31 13:49:08.637 17500 17500 I SELinux : SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.mycompany.myapp 
07-31 13:49:08.651  3631  4052 I ActivityManager: DSS on for com.mycompany.myapp and scale is 1.0
07-31 13:49:08.653  3631  3722 V WindowManager: finishDrawingLocked: mDrawState=COMMIT_DRAW_PENDING Window{4283642 u0 Splash Screen com.mycompany.myapp} in Surface(name=Splash Screen com.mycompany.myapp)
07-31 13:49:08.662  3631  3920 D GameManagerService: handleForegroundChange(). pkgName: com.mycompany.myapp, clsName: com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity,FgActivityName:com.mycompany.myapp/.MainActivity
07-31 13:49:08.663  3631  3920 D GameManagerService: notifyResumePause(). pkg: com.mycompany.myapp, type: 4, isMinimized: false, isTunableApp: false
07-31 13:49:08.663  3631  4052 D MARsPolicyManager: onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.mycompany.myapp, userId = 0
07-31 13:49:08.668  3631  7671 D GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgDataIncServer(). com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.669  3631  7671 D GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.669  3631  7671 D GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.669  3631  7671 D GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.669  3631  7671 D GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.670  3631  7671 D GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.670  3631  7671 D GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.671  3631  7671 D GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.671  3631  7671 D GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.673  3631  7671 D GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.673  3631  7671 D GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.717  3194  3194 D SurfaceFlinger:       GLES | 70a05848c0 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |  313,  349, 1029, 1622 | Splash Screen com.mycompany.myapp#0
07-31 13:49:08.747  3631  4052 D PackageManager: setEnabledSetting : userId = 0 packageName = com.mycompany.myapp cmp = androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService newState = 1 callingPackage = 10212/com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.798 17500 17500 D SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64
07-31 13:49:08.798 17500 17500 D SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-31 13:49:08.798  3631  3772 D MdnieScenarioControlService:  packageName : com.mycompany.myapp    className : com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity
07-31 13:49:08.799 17500 17500 E SoLoader:  SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
07-31 13:49:08.799 17500 17500 E SoLoader:  SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectApkSoSource[root = /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a]
07-31 13:49:08.799 17500 17500 E SoLoader:  Native lib dir: /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64
07-31 13:49:08.799 17500 17500 D SoLoader: libhermes.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64
07-31 13:49:08.802 17500 17500 D SoLoader: liblog.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64
07-31 13:49:08.802 17500 17500 D SoLoader: liblog.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-31 13:49:08.802 17500 17500 D SoLoader: libm.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64
07-31 13:49:08.802 17500 17500 D SoLoader: libm.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-31 13:49:08.802 17500 17500 D SoLoader: libdl.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64
07-31 13:49:08.803 17500 17500 D SoLoader: libdl.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-31 13:49:08.803 17500 17500 D SoLoader: libc.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64
07-31 13:49:08.803 17500 17500 D SoLoader: libc.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-31 13:49:08.811 17500 17500 D SoLoader: libhermes-executor-debug.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64
07-31 13:49:08.811 17500 17500 D SoLoader: libhermes-executor-debug.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-31 13:49:08.811 17500 17500 E SoLoader:  SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
07-31 13:49:08.811 17500 17500 E SoLoader:  SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectApkSoSource[root = /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a]
07-31 13:49:08.811 17500 17500 E SoLoader:  Native lib dir: /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64
07-31 13:49:08.811 17500 17500 D SoLoader: libhermes-executor-release.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64
07-31 13:49:08.861 17500 17524 D SoLoader: libfbjni.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64
07-31 13:49:08.863 17500 17524 D SoLoader: libandroid.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64
07-31 13:49:08.863 17500 17524 D SoLoader: libandroid.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
07-31 13:49:08.886 17500 17524 D SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-VSWi83B1RNj2nuqCcKLp5w==/lib/arm64
07-31 13:49:08.896  3631  4052 V WindowManager: Relayout Window{28a4b9a u0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity}: viewVisibility=0 req=1080x1848 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#110 ty=1 fl=#81810100 pfl=0x20000 wanim=0x10302fd vsysui=0x600 needsMenuKey=2 colorMode=0 naviIconColor=0}
07-31 13:49:08.901 17500 17524 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 17500
07-31 13:49:08.901  3194  3194 I SurfaceFlinger: id=189 createSurf (1080x1920),1 flag=404, com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity#0
07-31 13:49:08.903  3631  5018 W ActivityManager: crash : com.mycompany.myapp,0
07-31 13:49:08.905  3631  5018 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.mycompany.myapp/.MainActivity
07-31 13:49:08.905  3631  5018 W MultiScreenManagerService: moveTaskBackToDisplayIfNeeded(): root activity or app is null, task=TaskRecord{b074ccbd0 #871 A=com.mycompany.myapp U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}, rootActivity=null
07-31 13:49:08.912 17500 17527 D libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:08.922  3631  3655 I ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.mycompany.myapp u0
07-31 13:49:08.936  3194  3194 D SurfaceFlinger:       GLES | 70a05848c0 | 0000 | 0021 | 00 | 0100 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |    0,    0, 1080, 1920 | Splash Screen com.mycompany.myapp#0
07-31 13:49:08.968  3631  3655 D ViewRootImpl@cedd1c[myapp]: setView = DecorView@a530cab[myapp] TM=true MM=false
07-31 13:49:08.969  3631  3655 D ViewRootImpl@cedd1c[myapp]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
07-31 13:49:08.970  3631  5147 V WindowManager: finishDrawingLocked: mDrawState=COMMIT_DRAW_PENDING Window{28a4b9a u0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity} in Surface(name=com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity)
07-31 13:49:08.971 17139 17157 W PkgUtils: p: com.mycompany.myapp, u:0
07-31 13:49:08.976 17500 17500 V InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@7cbcba5 nm : com.mycompany.myapp ic=null
07-31 13:49:08.979  3631  3722 D ViewRootImpl@bd5a48d[myapp]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
07-31 13:49:08.979  3631  3722 D InputEventReceiver: channel '4283642 Splash Screen com.mycompany.myapp (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
07-31 13:49:08.979  3631  3722 D InputEventReceiver: channel '4283642 Splash Screen com.mycompany.myapp (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver.
07-31 13:49:08.979  3631  3655 V WindowManager: Relayout Window{d6f9efa u0 Application Error: com.mycompany.myapp}: viewVisibility=0 req=1015x442 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(wrapxwrap) gr=#11 sim=#120 ty=2003 fl=#1820002 pfl=0x110 fmt=-3 wanim=0x10302ec surfaceInsets=Rect(6, 6 - 6, 6) needsMenuKey=2 colorMode=0 naviIconColor=0}
07-31 13:49:08.986  3194  3194 D SurfaceFlinger:        HWC | 708d63b000 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |    7,    8, 1079, 1914 | com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity#0
07-31 13:49:08.986  3194  3194 D SurfaceFlinger: ,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |    7,    8, 1079, 1914 | Splash Screen com.mycompany.myapp#0
07-31 13:49:08.987  3194  3194 I SurfaceFlinger: id=190 createSurf (13x13),1 flag=4, Application Error: com.mycompany.myapp#0
07-31 13:49:08.996  3631  3655 D ViewRootImpl@cedd1c[myapp]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[32,775][1047,1217] result=0x27 surface={valid=true 515659157504} changed=true
07-31 13:49:09.001  3194  3194 D SurfaceFlinger:        HWC | 708d63b000 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |    7,    8, 1079, 1914 | com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity#0
07-31 13:49:09.001  3194  3194 D SurfaceFlinger:        HWC | 70a05848c0 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |    7,    8, 1079, 1914 | Splash Screen com.mycompany.myapp#0
07-31 13:49:09.001  3631  3655 D ViewRootImpl@cedd1c[myapp]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
07-31 13:49:09.013  3631  3655 V WindowManager: finishDrawingLocked: mDrawState=COMMIT_DRAW_PENDING Window{d6f9efa u0 Application Error: com.mycompany.myapp} in Surface(name=Application Error: com.mycompany.myapp)
07-31 13:49:09.013  3631  3655 D ViewRootImpl@cedd1c[myapp]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(32, 775 - 1047, 1217) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
07-31 13:49:09.019  3631  7968 V WindowManager: Relayout Window{28a4b9a u0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity}: viewVisibility=8 req=1080x1920 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#110 ty=1 fl=#81810100 pfl=0x20000 wanim=0x10302fd vsysui=0x600 needsMenuKey=2 colorMode=0 naviIconColor=0}
07-31 13:49:09.034  3631  7968 D PackageManager: getComponentMetadataForIconTray : com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity does not exist in mServices
07-31 13:49:09.034  3631  7968 D PackageManager: getComponentMetadataForIconTray : com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity does not exist in mProviders
07-31 13:49:09.034  3631  7968 D PackageManager: getComponentMetadataForIconTray : com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity does not exist in mReceivers
07-31 13:49:09.034  4034  4591 D ApplicationPackageManager: updateItemMetaDataForFixedIconScale: package: com.mycompany.myapp
07-31 13:49:09.035  3631  7968 D PackageManager: getSelectedMetaData : packageName(com.mycompany.myapp) or Metadata strings {[Ljava.lang.String;@e7a6623}
07-31 13:49:09.035  4034  4591 I ApplicationPackageManager: load=com.mycompany.myapp, bg=144-144, dr=144-144, forDefault=true, density=0
07-31 13:49:09.037  4034  4591 I ApplicationPackageManager: load=com.mycompany.myapp-crop, bg=144-144, dr=144-144
07-31 13:49:09.068  3194  3194 D SurfaceFlinger:       GLES | 708d63b000 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |  298,  333, 1031, 1636 | com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity#0
07-31 13:49:09.068  3194  3194 D SurfaceFlinger:       GLES | 70a05848c0 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |  298,  333, 1031, 1636 | Splash Screen com.mycompany.myapp#0
07-31 13:49:09.068  3194  3194 D SurfaceFlinger:   0.0, 1027.0,  454.0 |   66,  787, 1011, 1205 | Application Error: com.mycompany.myapp#0
07-31 13:49:09.085  3194  3194 D SurfaceFlinger:       GLES | 708d63b000 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |  346,  386, 1023, 1590 | com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity#0
07-31 13:49:09.085  3194  3194 D SurfaceFlinger: 0 | 0000 | 0020 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0 |  346,  38

Some of the stuff I've tested are:

https://dev.to/stan6453/how-to-fix-all-build-errors-in-react-nativeandroid-specific-241f
Error "couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes-executor-release.so"
React-Native :java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35895

I was expecting it to build a release mode that bundled everything correctly and didn't crash the app when I opened it.

Please double check which Gradle version is supported for the Android targetSDK API level you are trying to build https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin
